# Kafka Connect Hbase sink

Tags: apache-kafka, hbase, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to deploy `hbase` sink connector for `kafka` `(https://github.com/mravi/kafka-connect-hbase)`. So I downloaded and configured `Hbase` and Confluent Platform as per step 1 & 2.

Then it says,

- Copy `hbase-sink.jar` and `hbase-sink`.properties from the project build location to `$CONFLUENT_HOME/share/java/kafka-connect-hbase`

But I don't see `hbase-sink`.jar and `hbase-sink`.properties anywhere in the `Hbase` and confluent directory location. Any help where I can get them.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't see hbase-sink.jar and hbase-sink.properties

Sounds like you've not cloned that repo and ran `mvn clean package`, then opened up the target directory

---

As the other answer says, that project seems abandoned.

Try looking at this one too https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/sink/hbase.html

Comment: Thanks, Is the one from lenses.io a paid one ?

Comment: Not that I know of. It's open source on Github

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the Hbase connector from Confluent [kafka-connect-hbase](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hbase)? The one which you are using seems to be abandoned (no commits for the last 4 years).

[kafka-connect-hbase documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hbase/)

Comment: That one is "part of a Confluent Platform **subscription**", meaning it'll only work for 30 days for free